# Increase apache ant permgen space in Windows 7

Tags: ant

How to increase permgen space in apache 1.9.2
I looked for a solution and couldn't find. I'm calling "ANT" command from the build directory. I tried changing the antenv.cmd as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use the environmentvariable `ANT_OPTS` , as described in [ant manual](https://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html)
(see Environment Variables section) to set JVM parameters like f.e.:

```
-XX:PermSize -XX:MaxPermSize ... etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding

```
set ANT_OPTS = <values>
```

in /bin/ant.cmd